# Straight line become zigzagged when rotating in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am facing problem while I am trying to rotate a straight line in Illustrator: It becomes zigzagged:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Also, a bit more information about how you created the line and how you are rotating it would help us to answer the question for you.

Comment: check your file dpi 72 or 300

Comment: That's just the screen pixels by the look of it. The line is still straight. I would recommend sitting a little further from your screen though.

Comment: @atek It's in 300 dpi

Comment: @Chris I am facing this problem every time I draw a line or rectangle and trying to rotate it and even using star tool. Plz see these links

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/BC4lv

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/wZ97H

Comment: This is not a problem, it's the normal way that lines display on a computer screen when they are not just straight horizontal or vertical lines. The only way to not see this is to use a display with higher pixel density (retina as Apple call it) so that you can't see the pixels, but honestly this is fine and normal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about graphic design and no solution exists.

Comment: Thank You for the reply.I am using Windows10 for design and when I export any of my  design it appears this way.Is it okay?

Comment: This only happens with the Free Transform tool? Or the Image>Image Rotation does it too?

Comment: I am rotating through object> transform>rotate and using Illustrator CC 2014

Comment: You can avoid this by rotating your monitor, instead of what it displays. ... It is **unavoidable** because the pixels on your screen are rectangles.

Comment: @atek Illustrator documents have no resolution (the resolution you can set is for *raster effects only* and doesn't affect anything else).

Comment: Looks like AA is turned off though. @Cai

Comment: @joojaa ok, raster effect resolution has nothing to do with that though?

Comment: @joojaa that may be worth an answer though :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a non-issue unfortunately without re-inventing the wheel you can't change this - there is nothing wrong with your design or application :-) Consider a new monitor or rotation of your monitor